# How to pick an Image from personal profile while app is running in work profile

Tags: android, android-work-profile

My application is running in the work profile. From the application, I fire an intent to open the gallery app of Android which works perfectly. It shows me the list of application which can handle the intent in the work profile. There I also have an option to "switch to personal profile". When I choose the personal profile, it shows me the list of applications that can handle the intent in the personal profile. I choose one application and pick the image. 
Now in onActivityResult, I am getting the Uri which has authority and path like this -

```
Authority - 0@com.android.providers.downloads.documents
Path - /document/msf%3A4104
```

here 0 is the user info of personal profile. I used following code to check if it's the docuement URI but it returns false always -

```
DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)
```

From the developer document, I find this link https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri#getEncodedAuthority() 
but it has no documentation on how to resolve and access the files with these types of authorities.

This scenario can be produced with the work profile.Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: check this: https://developer.android.com/work/managed-profiles#sharing_files

Comment: `DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)`. What is the value of uri.toString() ?

Comment: @blackapps uri.toString() returns content://0@com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/msf%3A4104

Comment: I wonder why you need/use isDocumentUri(). If you just try to open an input stream and then try to read the contents.. then what happens? `InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);`.

Comment: `but it has no documentation on how to resolve and access the files with these types of authorities.` Ii think there is no difference. Why would it?

Comment: @blackapps I tried that, it resolved the issue.. the answer was always in front of me but couldn't see it.. thanks for help